# How to bind yii action in extjs

Tags: yii, extjs4

I am working in extjs+Yii. My yii action is:

```
public function actionCreateNew()
{
    $record=Qbquestionset::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("questionPaperId"=>1));

    foreach($record as $rec)
    {
        if($rec==NULL)
        {
            echo"Paper does not exists";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $rec->questionId;
            $record1=Qbquestion::model()->findByAttributes(array("questionId"=>$rec->questionId));
            echo "</br>". $record1->question;
            echo "</br>".CJSON::encode(array("Question"=>$record1->question));
        }

    }
}
```

This function is retrieving Questions and sending it in json format.
Now in extjs I had created model, view, controller and view as=
Model= Question.js

```
Ext.define('Balaee.controller.Question',
          {
    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores:['Question'],
    models:['Question','QuestionOption'],
    views:['question.Question','question.QuestionView'],
    init:function()
    {
        console.log("inside Question controller");


    },

             });
```

Store.js===

```
Ext.define('Balaee.store.Question', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'Balaee.model.Question',
autoLoad: true,
proxy:{
    type: 'ajax',
    //url:'data/poll.json',
    api: {
        //read: 'data/question.json',
        read: 'http://localhost/NewQuestion/index.php?r=QuestionBank/qbpaper/CreateNew',
    },
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        //root: 'questions',
    }
}
});
```

View=== questionView.js

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.question.QuestionView',
{
    extend:'Ext.view.View',
    id:'QuestionViewId',
    alias:'widget.questionView',
    store:'Question',
    config:
    {
        tpl:'<tpl for=".">'+
            '<div id="main">'+
            '</br>'+
            '<b>Question :-</b> {Question}</br>'+
            //'<p>-------------------------------------------</p>'+

            //'<tpl for="options">'+     // interrogate the kids property within the data
                //'<p>&nbsp&nbsp<input type="radio" name="opt" >&nbsp{option}</p>'+
            //'</tpl></p>'+

            '</div>'+
            '</tpl>',
        itemSelector:'div.main',    
    }
});//
```

So I am binding yii action to store by mentioning its url. But store is not retrieving any value. So what changes are needed to retrieve yii optputs in extjs store?

Answer (score 1):

One problem I can see is with your Yii action. You should return JSON result, while you returning something weird.

Try this:

```
public function actionCreateNew()
{
    $record = Qbquestionset::model()->findAllByAttributes(array("questionPaperId" => 1));
    $result = array();
    foreach($record as $rec) {
        if ($rec != NULL) {
            $result[] = $record1->question;
        }
    }

    echo CJSON::encode(array(
        'success' => true,
        'root' => $result,
        'total' => count($result)
    ));
}
```

You should also define `root: 'root'` property of reader.